# Solving summations of form $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^kx^i$ without Differentiation and Integration

Tags: sequences-and-series

The actual sum I'm looking to solve is $$\sum x^i(i^3-(i-1)^3)=(1-x)\sum x^ii^3$$ But I'd rather do a general answer first. I know the method of differentiation and integration but I'd like to do it without that. I remember seeing a method which reduced the power of $i$ on Brilliant but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for generating function and finite-difference methods? e.g., if $f(x)=\sum_i x^i i^2$, what's $xf(x)-f(x)$?

Comment: Let the partial sum be $S_N(x)$. Consider $S_N(x)$ and $x S_N(x)$. This might be pretty complicated at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt want to do the differention method due to the complexity. It's already complex enough at power 2

Comment: Important clarification - these aren't _differentiation_ methods; they're _difference_ methods. The two are somewhat similar, and in cases like this they certainly end up in the same place, but they shouldn't be conflated.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was reffering to differntiation methods though. I didn't know the difference method

Comment: We should be able to solve sums of $x^i i^n$ recursively starting from $x^{i+1} (i+1)^n - x^i i^n = x\cdot x^{i}[(i+1)^n - i^n] + (x-1)x^ii^n$. The term on the left telescopes when summed and on the right we have combinations of terms $x^i i^k$ for different $k$.

Comment: Differentiation would be e.g. starting with $\sum_ix^i=1/(1-x)$ and then noting that if we differentiate and multiply by $x$, the sum on the left becomes $\sum_iix^i$; it proceeds 'forward' from a base generating function to craft the GF for this sequence, as opposed to proceeding backwards from the starting sequence to determine its function.

Comment: Also, I'll note that it looks like you're already taking first steps; now that you have $(i+1)^3-i^3$ on the LHS, you should use the binomial theorem to expand out $(i+1)^3$ and perform the subtraction; you'll find a second-degree polynomial in $i$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki your First comment was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F_k(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} i^k x^i$, then (assuming $0^0 = 1$) $F_0(x) = 1 / (1 - x)$ and, for $k > 0$,
$$F_{k}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}(i + 1)^k x^{i + 1} = x \sum_{r = 0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}F_r(x),$$
which gives you $(1 - x)F_k(x)$ expressed through $F_r(x)$ with $r < k$.

This is just an example - there are other recurrences that you can get like this way.