# How to calculate the summation of $n \cdot 2^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, geometric-series

So I know that you can take the derivative of this and multiply by x and do integrals or something like that. However, I am just wondering if there is a way to come to the summation of the series without doing derivatives or integrals. Is there a simple way or would that way just be guess and check?

Comment: [Answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2906509/543769) a similar question some time ago...

Comment: (The same would work for finite sums.)

Comment: Already asked zillion times.

Answer (score 0):

$$4\cdot2^4+3\cdot2^3+2\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^1
\\=(4\cdot2^5+3\cdot2^4+2\cdot2^3+1\cdot2^2)-(4\cdot2^4+3\cdot2^3+2\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^1)
\\=4\cdot2^5-2^4-2^3-2^2-2^1
\\=4\cdot2^{4+1}-2^{4+1}+2.$$

The generalization is immediate.

Comment: where did you get the $(4\cdot2^5+3\cdot2^4+2\cdot2^3+1\cdot2^2)$

Comment: @Geralt: $\times 2$.

Comment: could you explain how you went from line 2 to line 3 @Yves Daoust

Comment: @Geralt: spend one minute doing the subtraction.

Comment: Shouldn't $-2^4-2^3-2^2-2^1$ be rewritten as $-2^5 +2$

Comment: @Geralt: you are right, fixing. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate post (many duplicates, also suggested in comments).  Next time, try searching before jumping in to answer so quickly.  You've been around long enough to know that.

Comment: All the more reason you should *not to have answered the thing.*  "Already asked a zillion times."  Thanks for acknowledging answering anyway was pretty sad a thing to do.

Comment: Yykes, Yves.  I'm chill.  Thanks for caring, but you need to take care of yourself, first.